# Add a new column in csv python

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

How do I add a new column at the very beginning of csv file? I know we can do it using pandas, but I am having issue with pandas so is there another way to do it? I have something that looks like this:

| a | b | c | d |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 |

I want to do this instead:

| letters | a | b | c | d |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| numbers | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 |

if the tables are not formatted properly here is a picture:
[Tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SYsif.png)

Comment: Just read the file one line at a time and write to a new file prepending each line with the additional information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you mean by *"I a am having issues"* with [pandas](/questions/tagged/pandas) ?
Have you tried using/running `df.insert(0, "letters", "numbers")` ?

Anyways, alternatively, you can use [`csv.reader`](https://docs.python.org/fr/3.6/library/csv.html#csv.reader) function from [csv](/questions/tagged/csv) module with a *listcomp* to insert the new column :

```
import csv

with open("input.csv", "r") as file:
    rows = [["letters" if idx == 0 else "numbers"] + row
            for idx, row in enumerate(csv.reader(file, delimiter=","))]

with open("output.csv", "w", newline="") as file:
    csv.writer(file, delimiter=",").writerows(rows)
```

Output :

```
from tabulate import tabulate #pip install tabulate

with open("output.csv", "r") as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file, delimiter=",")
    print(tabulate([row for row in reader]))

-------  -  -  -  -
letters  a  b  c  d
numbers  0  1  2  3
-------  -  -  -  -
```